# How to select consecutive rows till condition in other column is satisfied?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table (in Redshift) which has the following four columns:

```
cust_id | timestamp | color | visted_pages_sequence
```

I want to select the for each cust_id the rows between the `visted_pages_sequence LIKE '%first-page% and visted_pages_sequence LIKE '%end-page%`. Knowing that there could be sequences having just `visited_pages_sequence` which has just a row LIKE `%first-page%` and then nothing comes after that. And others having a rows sequence that have in visited_pages_sequence column a row which satisfies the condition LIKE `%first-page%`, a consecutive row satisfying `%mid-page-1%` another consecutive row satisfying the condition LIKE `%mid-page-2%` BUT: no row satisfying the condition LIKE `%end-page%`.

How to select the data, sorted by customer_ids?

Here is a sample of my table:

```
| cust_id | timestamp           | color   |   visited_page_sequence |
|---------|---------------------|---------|-------------------------|
| 54628   | 11/11/2015 11:46:00 |  black  |    this-first-page      |
|54628    | 11/11/2015 11:47:00 |  white  |    this-middle-page1    |
|94254    | 11/11/2015 11:48:00 |         |                         |
|45456    | 11/11/2015 11:49:00 |  braun  |    this-first-page      |
|45456    | 11/11/2015 11:50:00 |  beige  |    this-middle-page1    |
|45456    | 11/11/2015 11:52:00 |         |   this-end-page         |
|55411    | 11/11/2015 11:53:00 |  red    |                         |
|42462    | 11/11/2015 11:54:00 |  cyan   |     this-another-page   |
|24177    | 11/11/2015 11:55:00 |  orange |   this-first-page       |
|24177    | 11/11/2015 11:56:00 |  gray   |     this-next-page      |
|88888    | 11/11/2015 11:57:00 |  pink   |                         |
|94476    | 11/11/2015 11:58:00 |  black  |    this-first-page      |
|94476    | 11/11/2015 11:59:00 |  braun  |    this-middle-page1    |
|94476    | 11/11/2015 12:00:00 |         |    this-middle-page2    |
|94476    | 11/11/2015 12:01:00 |  white  |    this-end-page        |
|64579    | 11/11/2015 12:02:00 |  green  |    this-another-page    |
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
| cust_id | timestamp            | color     | visited_page_sequence |   
|---------|----------------------|-----------|-----------------------|
| 45456   | 11/11/2015 11:49:00  | braun     |this-first-page        |
| 45456   | 11/11/2015 11:50:00  | beige     |this-middle-page1      |
| 45456   | 11/11/2015 11:52:00  |           |this-end-page          |
| 94476   | 11/11/2015 11:58:00  | black     |this-first-page        |
| 94476   | 11/11/2015 11:59:00  | braun     |this-middle-page1      |
| 94476   | 11/11/2015 12:00:00  |           |this-middle-page2      |
| 94476   | 11/11/2015 12:01:00  | white     |this-end-page          |
```

PS: 
1) there COULD be more than one row per cust_id with visited_page_sequence like '%first-page%'
2) there COULD be more than one row per cust_id with visited_page_sequence like '%middle-page-1%' or middle-page-2 or any other middle pages not listed here
3) there is not more than one row per cust_id with visited_page_sequence like '%end-page%'
4) the combination of (cust_id, timestamp) has no duplicates

EDIT after comments: 
5) IF a value in visited_page_sequence  appears two times consecutively, just the last occurence should be returned!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: which database sqlserver /oracle

Comment: Amazon Redshift, which is based on PostgreSQL actually...

Comment: "there COULD be more than one row per cust_id with visited_page_sequence like '%first-page%'" - And how do you want to handle it? Consider a sequence like this: "fist-page, middle-page-1, middle-page-2, first-page, middle-page-3, end-page, middle-page-4, first-page, middle-page-5". What should be returned?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- there is not more than one row per `cust_id` with `visited_page_sequence like '%first-page%'`
- there is not more than one row per `cust_id` with `visited_page_sequence like '%end-page%'`
- the combination of `(cust_id, timestamp)` has no duplicates

you can use:

```
select t.*
from myTable f
join myTable l on l.cust_id = f.cust_id
join myTable t
  on  t.cust_id = f.cust_id
  and t.timestamp between f.timestamp and l.timestamp
where f.visited_page_sequence like '%first-page%'
  and l.visited_page_sequence like '%end-page%'
order by t.cust_id, t.timestamp
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a9XpGzGXDYoczArMTPHa2g/0)

Comment: Thank you. But there COULD be actually more than one row per cust_id with visited_page_sequence like '%first-page%'.

Comment: @ZelelB Then you should describe (in your question) all those edge cases and how to handle them.

Comment: edited as you proposed. Could you please edit your code accordingly, as I find your solution quite "elegant" yet simple.

Comment: It's simple because of the assumtions I made. The first query I wrote before posting the answer was [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ikf6P3W7M4jr6xFD9LiyCn/0).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to first find out the min/max timestamps per customer, filtering out rows outside of this range.
Something like:

```
/*
  for each customer, find out the min/max timestamp we are interested in,
  ie when they first visited a 'first-page' and last visited a 'end-page'
*/
WITH
min_max_by_customer AS (
  SELECT
    cust_id,
    MIN(
      CASE
        WHEN visited_page_sequence LIKE '%first-page%' THEN timestamp
        ELSE null
      END
    ) AS min_first_page_timestamp,
    MAX(
      CASE
        WHEN visited_page_sequence LIKE '%end-page%' THEN timestamp
        ELSE null
      END
    ) AS max_end_page_timestamp
  FROM i
  GROUP BY cust_id
),
/*
  fetch the actual data we're interested in (ie timestamp between first-page/end-page).
  also flag a row to be removed if the next row contains the same 'visited_page_sequence'
*/
rows_per_customer AS(
  SELECT
    i.*,
    visited_page_sequence = LEAD(visited_page_sequence) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS same_page_as_next_row
  FROM i
  JOIN min_max_by_customer
  USING (cust_id)
  WHERE i.timestamp BETWEEN min_first_page_timestamp AND max_end_page_timestamp
)
SELECT *
FROM rows_per_customer
WHERE same_page_as_next_row IS NOT TRUE /* XXX not the same as 'IS FALSE' due to SQL's three-value logic */
;
```

returns

```
┌─────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ cust_id │      timestamp      │ visited_page_sequence │
├─────────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│   45456 │ 2015-11-11 11:49:00 │  this-first-page      │
│   45456 │ 2015-11-11 11:50:00 │  this-middle-page1    │
│   45456 │ 2015-11-11 11:52:00 │ this-end-page         │
│   94476 │ 2015-11-11 11:58:00 │  this-first-page      │
│   94476 │ 2015-11-11 11:59:00 │  this-middle-page1    │
│   94476 │ 2015-11-11 12:00:00 │  this-middle-page2    │
│   94476 │ 2015-11-11 12:01:00 │  this-end-page        │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Quite nice. But I edited a little bit the question. Could you take a look, and tell me, if your proposed code is still working well after I added the details of possible combinations of unique vs non-unique values?

Comment: @ZelelB: as long as a customer has at least one `LIKE %first-page%` AND a `LIKE %end-page%` this query will return all rows between the first (ie earliest) 'first-page' and the last 'end-page' (though this one should be unique according to your question).  A customer with no `LIKE %end-page%` will not appear in the results. If you want the rows between the LAST 'first-page' and 'end-page' simply change the `MIN` to `MAX` in the `WITH min_max_by_customer` query.

Comment: Perfect! It works as I want it. Just a small edit and we're done here: The returned dataset contains sometime multiple consecutive same value in the column visited_page_sequence. How to get just the last occurence please? This happens because for example 1 millisecond in the timestamp increased and customer is still in the same step, let's say: 'this-middle-page2'. Could you please tell me what I have to change to get just the last one?

Comment: @ZelelB: edited my answer. You should edit your question to reflect the new requirements too.

Comment: edited the question accordingly. A last thing: Let's say I want to count per day the number of customer_id which atteined each step (%end-page%, '%first-page%, '%middle-page-1%' or '%middle-page-2%' and group them by day. Is it a small fix in the code above? Tried everything and got to nothing right. Could you help out with this last point? Thank you so much!

Comment: I mean, the sequence then must start with visited_page_sequence LIKE  '%first-page% but must not end with  '%end-page%. It could end with '%middle-page-1% or '%middle-page-2%. How to count how many cust_ids per attained each level ('%first-page%', '%middle-page-1%', '%middle-page-2%' and '%end-page%')?

Comment: Asking another question which the whole details will not bring any answers, as the question will be too complicated. That's why I've just commented it here. I will edit the question, if you have a solution for doing this.